# AWS elasticsearch API _cluster is not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

According to Amazon documentation, AWS elasticsearch Service supports the API _cluster, but this command not working:

```js
curl -XGET 'https://search-aa-kfrqt6kjja5w7asrt7hi.sa-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_cluster/state?pretty'
{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/state' is not allowed."}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg-supported-operations.html

the cluster with template "allow open access to this domain"

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:sa-east-1:7183736:domain/aa-ca/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `application/json` header:

`curl -H "Content-type:application/json" https://search-aa-kfrqt6kjja5w7asrt7hi.sa-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_cluster/stats?pretty`

Actually, I took a look at documentation and it does not show the `/_cluster/state` in supported operations.

> Supported Amazon ES Operations: 
>   
> ...
>   
>  /_cluster/health
>   
>  /_cluster/settings for three properties (PUT only)
>   
> /_cluster/stats 
>   
> ...